# Careers cuts benefits in mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, mobile-web, careers-germany

It should be pretty apparent in the following two screenshots.

This one is cropped from normal upright view:
[image]

And this one was taken in landscape:

[image]

I circled the same areas...

As one can see the upright scale cuts away some text

Comment: Didn't know Careers even got mobile theme, looks like it can't be reached manually like on all other SE sites.

Comment: You can actually switch to a mobile device view with the chrome developer tools... then again I looked up the job again... and the Benefits vanished. Interestingly on my mobile phone they're still there. might be because the URL is a little different since I came from the app feed.

Comment: Marking this as completed as it seems this has been fixed. If it's still broken for you, can you update your post with a link to the company page you're viewing, and what device your using?